# What is NEIKEv2Provider, and why is it preventing me from accessing the internet?

Tags: macos

I recently updated my work computer (2015 Mac Book Pro). After logging in I got a request from system reading:

```
NEIKEv2Provider wants to use your confidential information stored in "Nord VPN" in your keychain.
```

I accidentally denied access and my computer will not connect to internet. although I am still connected to wifi. I know that this is the problem because on a different user I allowed permission and was able to connect no problem. I did some searching and found that the it lives in this directory:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/NetworkExtension.framework/Plugins/NEIKEv2Provider.appex/Contents/MacOS/NEIKEv2Provider
```

So my question is: What is this and why is it required for internet connection and can I grant permissions to it or bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem after installing a VPN client. Permissions appear to be missing. Check this link, especially the section "Important steps for a successful connection": https://protonvpn.com/support/protonvpn-mac-vpn-application/